# Node js/React app pipeline not building right

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

Following this link below, I can succesfully set up the build stage, but for some reasons I am getting this error message for what concerns the test stage:

[image: error message]

I am not able to figure out why I am getting this error message.

https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-node-js-and-react-app-with-npm/#on-windows